# Compile on save is not working for ASP.NET 5 apps in VS 2015 RC

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 RC on a clean Win 8.1 machine and created an app from the default template Asp .NET 5 Preview Template / Web Site.

If I hit run, the web app starts, but changing for example the `ViewBag.Message` in the home controller isn't reflecting the change in the browser after reloading the page.

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

I looked around but couldn't find the cause of the issue. IE11 and Chrome behaves the same. Client-side caching is disabled. This article suggests it should be working: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are not starting the application with debugging. For compile on the fly to work, the app must be started without debugging.

Comment: You're right. it works as you said for IISExpress, but DNX stops. Is that a known limitation?

Comment: Yes, it is by design. Long story short: we cannot recompile the code if it is loaded by dnx so we have to kill the process, recompile and then restart the process. That's also the reason why you cannot have a debugger attached

Comment: Has this changed at all since the move to the 'dotnet' toolchain and the .Net Core 1.0 release?